# what is wrong in this code in c++

Tags: c++

this is the problem https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1042
and the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int A,B,C
 int main ()
 {
cin >> A >> B >> C;
if (A > B > C)
cout <<C<<"\n"<<B<<"\n"<<A<<"\n\n";
else if (B > A > C)
cout <<C<<"\n"<<A<<"\n"<<B<<"\n\n";
else if (C > A > B)
cout <<B<<"\n"<<A<<"\n"<<C<<"\n\n";
else if (A > C > B)
cout <<B<<"\n"<<C<<"\n"<<A<<"\n\n";
else if (C > B > A)
cout <<A<<"\n"<<B<<"\n"<<C<<"\n\n";
else  {
(B > C > A);
cout <<A<<"\n"<<C<<"\n"<<B<<"\n\n";}

cout <<A<<"\n"<<B<<"\n"<<C<<endl;

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You forgot the question...

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen, why do you think it does not happen like you expect it to happen?

Comment: the question is in what is wrong with this code in c++ ?

Comment: @farah: "spot the error" is not always a good way to resolve problems. In this case, it's a very obvious misunderstanding of how the language works, but in general, "my code has a bug, can somone spot it" should contain at least an explanation of what is actually happening, and what you expect to have happen.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear since I see umpteen things wrong with this code, and the OP doesn't indicate any particular of them.

Comment: You're determined to dump this garbage [all](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98114/32391) [over](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/290861/110531), huh? Read [ask], and expect to be question-banned in very short order.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that `if(A > B > C)` becomes `if (A > (B > C))` - in other words, you're comparing `A` to the `true` or `false` result of `B > C`, which will be true for all values where `A` of `2` or greater, regardless of the values of `B` and `C`.

The fix is to compare `A > B` separately from `B > C`, so use `if (A > B && B > C)` or some similar construct.

Answer (score 2):

You have to trnasform things like:

```
(A > B > C)
```

into:

```
(A>B && B>C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditions in the if statements are wrong. For example condition

```
if (A > B > C)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( A > B ) > C)
```

In this case condition ( A > B ) is evaluated to either `true` or `false`  and the condition is equivalent to either to

```
if ( true > C)
```

or

```
if ( false > C)
```

It is obvious that it is not what you want to get.

So the original condition has to be rewritten like

```
if (A > B && B > C )
```

But even in this case the program will be wrong because it does not consider cases when the variables could be equal each other. So the valid condition will look like

```
if (A >= B && B >= C )
```

And the program will not compile because at least here there is a typo

```
int A,B,C
         ^^^
```

You forgot to place a semicolon

```
int A,B,C;
```

Also there is no sense to declare variables A, B, C as global

```
int A,B,C;
int main ()
{
//...
```

It is better to declare them as local variables of function main

```
int main ()
{
    int A, B, C;
//...
```

And this code snippet is wrong

```
else  {
(B > C > A);
cout <<A<<"\n"<<C<<"\n"<<B<<"\n\n";}

cout <<A<<"\n"<<B<<"\n"<<C<<endl;
```

I think you mean simply

```
else  cout <<A<<"\n"<<C<<"\n"<<B<<endl;
```